# Positioning text underneath each other

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I position the text?

Expected result:

```
My title: Text text text text
text text text text text ...  <-- First word of the second line right below the heading
```

But i get the next result:

```
My title: Text text text text
          text text text text text ...
```

Also, the child goes to the outside of the parent's block

Code:

```
  <View style={styles.row}>
     <Text style={styles.text}> My title: </Text>
     <Text style={styles.value}>
       "Text text text text text text text text text ..."
     </Text>
  </View>
```

Style:

```
 row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Text` element (the one containing all the "text") in a `View`.

```
  <View style={styles.row}>
     <Text style={styles.text}> My title: </Text>
     <View style={styles.column}>
        <Text style={styles.value}>
          "Text text text text text text text text text ..."
        </Text>
     </View>
  </View>
```